# Combining google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob and google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've got images stored as [Blobs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob) in Google Cloud Storage and I can see amazing capabilities offered by [get_serving_url()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/services/bundled/google/appengine/api/images/get_serving_url) which requires a blob_key as its first parameter. But I cannot see anyway to get a key from the Blob - am I mixing up multiple things called Blobs?

I'm using Python3 on GAE.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below but you'll need to first [enable](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access) the Bundled Services API

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

# Create the cloud storage file name
blobstore_filename = f"/gs/{<your_file_name>}"

# Now create the blob_key from the cloud storage file name
blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)
```